# Bootstrap modal with image gallery swap

Tags: jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, gallery

I'm creating an image gallery where you can click on thumbnails, and then the thumbnail image swaps with the big image in the gallery.

This all works out, after that you can click onto the big image and then the Bootstrap modal window will appear.

This also works out, but somehow the previous / next buttons aren't working. Meaning it should show the previous or next big image.

A demo can be found here: http://hosted.dehaanmedia.nl/resources/imagegallery/

The javascript can be found at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6jz3yoq/)

I think the problem is within line 23 `var index = jQuery(this).parent('.bigimage img').index();`

Comment: Instead of changing the `href` attribute to the `index` value of the image, you need to make a function that changes the `src` attribute of the image in the modal with the correct big-image index. (did I made myself clear?)

Comment: Well, i'm pretty noob and created this of a couple of tutorials. I don't have a clue on how to change this.

Comment: Check line 47 of this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ytw1ds7z/ IDK where you save your images but this should work (note: it's a dirty `src` attribute change) just remember to change the `/path/to/you/images/big/` path to match the ones you have.    
This should get you started.

Comment: I tried allot of things with your new code. It's still not working. Can you fix this? I can pay you if you like to..

Comment: Check the code in the answer I gave.

Comment: I created a new Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/p8vnrn59/1/. Strangely i can't get it to work, or did i use your old code?

Comment: see edited answer, I forgot event delegation, it's now working (I updated your fork)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to match your image path http://jsfiddle.net/p8vnrn59/3/ as you forgot to add the image name to the code as I advised you. in line `47`
Your alert is working https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9TdI.jpg
note: there are some minor bugs that I'm certain you can fix; I'm now working and have no real-time to be arounf this fiddle.

Comment: I changed the code like you created in jsfiddle, which i'm very thankful for. Somehow it doesn't react on the previous or next button. I created an alert, but it's not alerting.

Comment: Edited the answer to show your `alert()` working; I also changed the code (notice /4/ = version four of the fiddle) because I found a bug in the code